# TypeError: Object expected onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

getting error on passing  onclick function as props in menu component.js  from main component 
code is compiling without error but iam getting error when click on any dish to get details 
passing onclick as props from main component

codwe is wokring fine without onclick function without passsing it as props and calling it directly from another component instead of main but that would violate the single responsibility rule

browser error

TypeError: Object expected
onClick

```
| function RenderMenuItem ({dish, onClick}) {
   6 |     return (
   7 |         <Card
>  8 |             onClick={() => onClick(dish.id)}>
     | ^
   9 |             <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
  10 |             <CardImgOverlay>
  11 |                 <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
```

code

Main component.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';

class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dishes: DISHES,
        selectedDish: null
    };
  }

  onDishSelect(dishId) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish: dishId});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="primary">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onClick={(dishId) =>{ this.onDishSelect(dishId)}} />
        <DishDetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === this.state.selectedDish)[0]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Menu Component.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay,
    CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

    function RenderMenuItem ({dish, onClick}) {
        return (
            <Card
                onClick={() => onClick(dish.id)}>
                <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                <CardImgOverlay>
                    <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                </CardImgOverlay>
            </Card>
        );
    }

    const Menu = (props) => {

        const menu = props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1"  key={dish.id}>
                    <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} onClick={props.onClick} />
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {menu}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

export default Menu;
```

Comment: just rename your parameter from `{dish, onClick}` to `{dish, onClickHandler}`

Comment: @hassan your code is working fine. I shown alert on onDishSelect and alert dialog is shown.

Comment: kip `onClick` is ok as a prop name. Can you provide a minimal example that repros issue in a codesandbox for debug live? I don't see any obvious errors in the shared code. I may change it up and just pass `this.onDishSelect` as the onClick callback (versus proxying it with anonymous function) but what you have seems fine.

Comment: @DrewReese https://rdv5t.csb.app/

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing an `onClick` callback to `Menu` in `App`

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="primary">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <Menu
          dishes={this.state.dishes}
          onClick={dishId => console.log("dishId", dishId)} // <-- pass onClick callback
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit focused-microservice-bm1u5]